# Antd Timepicker - don't scroll to selected value

Tags: javascript, reactjs, antd

I don't want to scroll Timepicker to the position where the selected value is on top of the list. I want it to remain in the place where it was before the selection was done.

I tried scrolling to the top of the list after selecting the value and see what will happen, I noticed that the scroll to the top is called before the scroll to the currently selected value.

[Scrolling animation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uxrG5.gif)

```
<TimePicker
      onSelect={moment => {
        const x = document.querySelector(`.ant-picker-time-panel-column`);
        x?.scrollTo({ top: 0 });
        return;
      }}
      {...props}
/>
```

I don't know how to prevent default actions here, because the argument of `onSelect` function is a moment object, not an HTMLElement. Is there any workaround for how it can be done?

antd v4.8.4, but probably it's a problem for all versions

Comment: Does merely selecting the hour or minute part actually fire the onSelect event? https://ant.design/components/time-picker#api says _"executes when a value is selected"_ - which I think might mean when you actually click the "OK" button? _"onChange: A callback function, can be executed when the selected time is changing"_ might be closer to what you need here, I think.

Comment: @CBroe onChange is called only when OK button is clicked (I hid it in my case, but it doesn't matter when it comes to my problem), onSelect is called when either hours or minutes are selected. Just after selection the scroll to selected value is performed as you see on attached gif, so it has to have something in common with onSelect

Comment: Not sure if this _has_ any "prevent default" mechanism build in - because why should it, a need to prevent the user from selecting the hour/minute they just did, should not arise in any normal use cases.